# Indy TIdSocksServer not forwarding traffic

Tags: delphi, indy, socks

I am attempting to create a SOCKS 4/5 server, and I would like to use the Indy `TIdSocksServer` component as the foundation. It seems straight forward enough and simple to use, but I must be missing something.

I dropped a `TIdSocksServer` onto a new Form and configured the following:

- Active: True
- AllowSocks4: True
- AllowSocks5: True
- Bindings: 0.0.0.0:43334
- Default Port: 80
- Intercept: null
- IOHandler: null

I added code to display `'connect'` in a `TMemo` upon connection:

```
procedure TForm1.IdSocksServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('connect');
end;
```

I configured ProxyChains on a Linux host:

/etc/proxychains.conf

```
...
socks5 10.0.0.56 43334
```

When I execute the App and try to connect using ProxyChains, I get the following error:

```
kelly@ubuntu:~/home$ proxychains curl www.google.com
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| www.google.com
|S-chain|-<>-10.0.0.56:43334-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<--timeout
|DNS-response|: www.google.com does not exist
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com
```

I can confirm that the connection is established, because the text `'connect'` gets added to the Memo. I also used Wireshark and observed the three-way handshake and teardown between my Ubuntu host and the Windows host.

It seems the issue is that the traffic is reaching the SOCKS server, but not getting forwarded. I acknowledge that this is absolute minimum code, but I am under the impression that the `TIdSocksServer` component would take care of forwarding the traffic, and I would add in supporting functions such as validating credentials for SOCKS5, etc.

Comment: The error is complaining about a timeout. Indy TCP servers are multi-threaded, events like `OnConnect` are fired in worker threads, and it is not safe to access VCL/FMX UI controls from outside of the main UI thread, so you very well could be causing a deadlock. Does the problem go away if you remove the Memo message, or at least synchronize it to the main UI thread properly?

Comment: Can you provide the Wireshark capture of the connection between ProxyChains and `TIdSocksServer`? How far is the SOCKS traffic actually reaching before it fails? Is the `OnBeforeSocksConnect` event being fired with its `VHost` parameter set to `’www.google.com’`? Is the `OnException` event being fired?

Comment: Thank you Remy. Your first comment identified the issue. The problem went away as soon as I removed the TMemo access.

Answer (score 0):

Remy identified the issue with my code. In order to verify that the server was receiving connections I added a procedure which wrote to a TMemo component, which was causing a deadlock. To fix the error all I had to do was remove the procedure which was updating the TMemo component. Works as expected.

Comment: To access the `TMemo` safely in the server's events, you just have to sync with the main UI thread, such as via `TThread.Synchronize()`/`TIdSync`, `TThread.Queue()`/`TIdNotify`, or any other inter-thread communication of your choosing.